# Are positive numbers faster than negative

Tags: floating-point

I'm wondering, do positive numbers represented in format with floating point take less time for calculation than negative?

And does it depend on architecture or anything else? And should I even care about that?

Comment: No. No. And: No.

Comment: Worry about O(n), not O(constant) issues.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: O(constant) issues may be worth a great deal of money. (Although, to be fair, my employer did have a large coefficient in the value function, like 10^9 units.)

Comment: Why would you expect negative numbers to be slower?

Answer (score 2):

No, to all of those. There actually is a set of floating point numbers that are slower to work with than the others — the “subnormal numbers” - but there is generally no need to worry about them.

Comment: FYI, the IEEE-754 standard uses “subnormal” to refer to numbers below the normals. In some floating-point formats, numbers may have multiple representations, and one of them, with a non-zero leading digit, may be designated the normal representation while others are denormalized representations. Then the question of normal or denormalized is about the representation, not the number. The subnormal numbers are below the range where numbers can be represented in the normal form at all, so they necessarily have denormalized representations. So normal or subnormal is about the number itself.

Comment: (Not everybody uses this or is precise about terminology. E.g., Intel documentation may use “denormal” to refer to the subnormal numbers. But following the standard is good practice.)

Comment: Fair enough, edited.

Comment: Re "but there is generally no need to worry about them". This is heavily context dependent. To my knowledge, the speed of handling sub-normals in single precision (IEEE-754 `binary32`) is a recurring issue in certain DSP task, in particular IIR filters. Another area known to be negatively affected by slow handling of sub-normals is shallow water equations.

Comment: Yes, hence my summation that there is generally no reason to worry about them. I feel entirely comfortable giving that guidance to the OP.